# How to convert all types of files format that downloaded from url to pdf by using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, pdf-generation

So, I have a case that I need to change all types of format (JPEG, PNG, doc, etc) from file that has been downloaded from url to pdf.


**The process that I want:**

First, there is a url that being generated by some application to the spreadsheet.
This url contain a file with not specified format (So, it can be JPEG, png, doc, pdf, etc). I need to download the file from the url and convert it to pdf format. After convert the file to pdf format, then the converted file will be saved in google drive and the file link from google drive will be inserted on spreadsheet.

***Notes:***

So, If this kind of thing is **impossible** to do, then **you can make the other way** like if the file format is .csv, .xlsx, .xls, .png, .jpeg, .pdf, or .doc, then it will convert the file to .pdf.


This is the illustration of the spreadsheet that I want to make:

| Url File | Drive link |
| --- | --- |
| https://..../file1.jpeg | https://drive/.../file1.pdf |
| https://..../file2.csv | https://drive/..../file2.pdf |

I have already made the code, but my code is still get the error because I only change the format (.doc) from the filename (filename.doc -> filename.pdf) and when I download the file it will not open because of that. If you guys have any suggestion to fix my code or have any different answer, It can be very helpful! Thank you


Here is the code that I've made:

```
function convert() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("");
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 var folder_id = '';
 var array = [];
 
 for (let i in data.length) {
   if (data[i][2] != "" && data[i][16] == "") { //condition for if column 3 is having a url and the drive link is still empty, then get the url
    array.push([data[i][2]]);
    
    var get_name = array.toString().split("/")[7]; //to get the file name
    
    var deleteformat= get_name .toString().split(".")[0]; //to delete the format

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(array, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
    var rc = response.getResponseCode();

   if (rc == 200) {
    var fileBlob = response.getBlob().setName(deleteformat+ '.pdf');
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id );
    if (folder != null) {
      var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
      var fileName = file.getName();
    }
  }
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id ).getFiles();
  while (file.hasNext()) {
    var xfile = file.next();
    if (xfile.getName() == fileName) {
      var file_id = xfile.getId();
      var url = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id ).getUrl();
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(i + 1, 17).setValue(url);
  sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).clearContent();
}
}
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to convert the all types of file format to pdf @Rubén

Comment: The code that I've made still not working because it's only change the format on the file name (like filename.jpeg -> filename.pdf)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what is missing to your code and make explicit what you are asking (please bear in mind that question should be specific), show what you tried to make the code fit your needs and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén I already editing my question. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @KJ I apologize if I misunderstand your answer. So, I have to using third party application to convert the files, right?

Comment: Hi there @AskingBob! As others have pointed out, this question is too generic to have a clear answer. If you point out which file format specifically you want to convert to PDF, I could help you better. Show some examples if needed.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Hello! Thank you for answering! Actually, I want to convert all types of file format from the start, but if that impossible to do then you can try to convert  (.csv, .xlsx, .xls, .png, .jpeg, .pdf, .doc) to .pdf. I apologize if it's too many or too much to ask

Comment: If you have other suggestion, I open for it. I want to convert more than one types of file format like .csv, .xlsx, .xls, .png, .jpeg, .pdf, and .doc will be converted to .pdf.  Example: I have a url for a file that containing the format like as I mentioned before (.csv, .xlsx, .xls, .png, .jpeg, .pdf, and .doc), then It will convert it to .pdf. File1.csv, File2.xlsx, and File3.docx, then it will convert all of the format to .pdf (File1.pdf, etc). Thank you for your offer to help! @Jacques-GuzelHeron

Comment: @AskingBob Please edit your answer to clarify which format you want to convert. You mentioned different data formats (records, sheets, images...), choose one in particular for the sake of this question. Please be aware that right now the question is too broad to have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Blob.getAs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getAs(String)), like this:

`var fileBlob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(deleteformat + '.pdf');`

You will also have to fix the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` line so that it references a URL rather an array.

Comment: The array contain the url. I will try your suggestion, thank you for answering

Comment: You need to reference a specific URL in the array rather than referencing the whole array. But that is a different question. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: I try using the getAs() and get the error (Exception: Conversion from text/csv to application/pdf failed.)

Comment: the array already referencing the specific array that need to convert. If there are 2 array, then it will convert the first url that has been pushed and after the converting already finished, then the second url will getting processed. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: You are using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(array, ...)`. The `array` variable points to an Array object. The `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` method expects an URL as a text string. Try `UrlFetchApp.fetch(get_name, ...)`. This question is about converting an image to a PDF. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).